# Issue with the view when the Timer completes

Tags: android

I am using the following code:

```
public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

        public CountDown(long millisInFuture) {
            super(millisInFuture, 1000); 
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Integer milisec = new Integer(new Double(millisUntilFinished)
                    .intValue());
            Integer cd_secs = milisec / 1000;
            Integer hours = cd_secs / 3600;
            Integer minutes = (cd_secs % 3600) / 60;
            Integer seconds = (cd_secs % 3600) % 60;
            timerText.setText(String.format("%02d", hours) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", seconds));
            long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        }
    }
```

I am displaying multiple timers on the same screen.

The problem I am facing is that , when the timers completes its duration , the timer is displayed as "00:00:01"

Since multiple timers(consider 3 timers) are running with different durations , I can't hard code on the onFinish() , since on hardcoding I am getting error since other timers are still running when the one of the timer has completed.

```
public void onFinish() {
            secText.setText("00");
}
```

Kindly provide your inputs.

Is there any problem with the source code, why its not changing to "00:00:00" & stopping to "00:00:01" when the timer has completed?

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Integer and Double? These are autoboxed values and as such are slower. Also why are you using

```
Integer milisec = new Integer(new Double(millisUntilFinished).intValue());
```

when

```
int milisec = (int) millisUntilFinished;
```

should do the same thing. Also

```
int cd_secs = milisec / 1000;
int hours = cd_secs / 3600;
int minutes = (cd_secs % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = (cd_secs % 3600) % 60;
```

Should do the same thing

EDIT

The problem is most likely you're setting the interval too high in your call to the parent constructor. try `super(millisInFuture, 100)` Should work more reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. wanted to know , from where should I call the if (milisec < 1000)
{
     // display 00:00:00 i.e. finished
}

Comment: at the end of the onTick function. This may fix rounding problems, not that I can see them...

Comment: The problem is unsolved , still it is ending at 00:00:01 .         But if I am changing the public CountDown(long millisInFuture) {
   super(millisInFuture, 10);
  }           from super(millisInFuture,1000) to super(millisInFuture,10) , its ending at "00:00:00"

Comment: Ah yes. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html The 2nd number in the constructor is the interval between ticks. Before, with 1000, you where missing the final tick, most likely due to scheduling issues. If you set it to anything from 100-500 you'll most likely get your 00:00:00 to display constantly without too much inefficency

Comment: I have an issue changing to "10" from "1000"  , I am playing audio file when the timer reaches 5 seconds & then till it decreases & reaches 0 . If I am using "10" as the interval , then the beep is being played multiple(2-3 times) each time instead of once . It is  being played once when the interval is "1000"                         Within the onTick() , if (timeLeft <= 5) {         playAlertSound(R.raw.beep);
    }

Comment: If I set the interval as "100" , then the no of times the onTick method will be called will be more , & so for a single second , I'll be getting multiple beeps. Better to explain , when the duration reaches 5 sec , instead of 1 beep , its playing 2-3 beeps , since the onTick is being called more than once

Comment: So you want it to beep every second for the final 5 seconds? Then add a variable int lastbeep = 6; and then check within the tick if seconds < lastbeep. If is it, then play your beep and update lastbeep. This is with keeping the 100 or 10 interval